# ¿Cómo agregar un input invisible pero que pueda escribir o al menos el focus este activo en el?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un input al que con una funcion se le pasa el focus pero quiero que no se vea pero pueda escribir en el, los atributos disabled y los estilos visibility:hidden y display:none no me funcionan,
Tampoco me ayuda quitrle los bordes en css por que al hacerle focus con mi funcion este se ve activo con los bordes resaltados y el puntero sobre este. Gracias

Comment: prueba darle opacity: 0 con css. Si el input es hidden no se puede enfocar

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era lo que buscaba

Answer (score 5):

Un input con la propiedad `hidden` no es enfocable, tampoco los `display: none`. Se me ocurre que tal vez puedas ponerle la opacidad a 0 y posicionarlo de forma absoluta, así es casi como si no estuviera.

Prueba esto a ver qué tal.

> Si cargas el snippet y no pulsas en nada, directamente el foco se va al input, aunque el h1 diga que pulses en el body.

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let text = document.getElementById("content");

function setText(value){
  content.innerHTML = value;
}

function focus(){
  input.focus();
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', focus());
```

```css
#input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="focus()">
  <input type="text" id="input" onblur="focus()" onkeyup="setText(this.value)">
  <h1 id="content">Pulsa en el body y escribe...</h1>
</body>
```